# NodeJS: синхронный цикл на примере заполнения объекта парами ключ-значение

Tags: node.js

Никак не могу разобраться с промисами. Задача в исходном виде: наполнить объект `objectWillBeFilled` парами ключ-значение и вернуть его. В таком коде этого не произойдёт из-за асинхронности NodeJS:

```
'use strict';

const glob = require('glob');

function testFunction(){

    let objectWillBeFilled = {};

    glob(/* Glob шаблон */, (errors, files) => {
        files.forEach( (value, index, array) => {
            // наполняем objectWillBeFilled ...
        });
    });
    return objectWillBeFilled;
}

console.log(testFunction());
```

Пытался сделать таким образом, но видимо, недопонял чего-то с промисами:

```
function testFunction(){

    let objectWillBeFilled;

    let promise = new Promise( (resolve, redject) => {

        glob(/* Glob шаблон */, (errors, files) => {
            files.forEach( (value, index, array) => {
                // наполнение объекта objectWillBeFilled
            });
        });

        reject(objectWillBeFilled);

    });

    webpackEntryPointsPromise.then((objectWillBeFilled) => {
        return objectWillBeFilled;
    });

}

console.log(testFunction());
```

Comment: в return функции вы никак не засунете асинхронный результат, тут либо колбэк либо `return promise` + `testFunction().then((objectWillBeFilled) => {...})`

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. Вы бы не могли бы хотя бы примерно решение набросать на основе моего кода, а то так без опыта с промисами не получается сделать полное решение из того, что Вы написали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с callback (не знаю асинхронный ли glob):

```
'use strict';

const glob = require('glob');

function testFunction(callback){
    let objectWillBeFilled = {};
    glob(/* Glob шаблон */, (errors, files) => {
        files.forEach( (value, index, array) => {
            // наполняем objectWillBeFilled ...
        });
    });
    callback(objectWillBeFilled);
}

testFunction(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

С промисами:

```
function testFunction(){    
    let objectWillBeFilled;    
    let promise = new Promise( (resolve, redject) => {
        glob(/* Glob шаблон */, (errors, files) => {
            files.forEach( (value, index, array) => {
                // наполнение объекта objectWillBeFilled
            });
        });
        resolve(objectWillBeFilled);
    });
    return promise;
}

testFunction().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!